# Prove that a vector x from L2[a,b] is in the subspace generated by f1,f2,f3

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

Let $f_1(t)=e^t$, $f_2(t)=e^{it}$ and $f_3(t)=e^{-it}$. Prove that a vector $x$ from L2[a,b] is in the subspace generated by $f_1,f_2,f_3$ if and only if $x$ verifies the differential equation $x'''-x''+x'-x=0$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  As written, this question isn't likely to get a lot of attention.  But, if you update it with information about what you've tried and where you're getting stuck, I'm sure somebody will be happy to give you some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

To begin, we note that each of the functions

$f_1(t) = e^t, \; f_2(t) = e^{it}, f_3(t) = e^{-it} \in L_2[a, b] \tag 1$

satisfy the differential equation

$x''' - x'' + x' - x = 0, \tag 2$

as is easily verified by simply substituting the $f_i(t)$, $1 \le i \le 3$ into (2) and performing the indicated operations.  Then if

$f(t) = c_1 f_1(t) + c_2 f_2(t) + c_3 f_3(t) \in L_2[a, b], \tag 3$

$f(t)$ also satisfies (2) by linearity; since the functions (3) are precisely those in the subspace

$V = \langle f_1(t), f_2(t), f_3(t) \rangle \subset L_2[a, b], \tag 4$

we see that every element of this subspace $V$ obeys (2).

To go the other way, we find the solutions to the given differential equation (2).  If we make the tentative hypothesis that there exist solutions of the form

$x = e^{rt}, \tag 5$

so that

$x' = re^{rt}, \; x'' = r^2 e^{rt}, \; x''' = r^3 e^{rt}, \tag 6$

we find that

$r^3 e^{rt} - r^2 e^{rt} + re^{rt} - e^{rt} = x''' - x'' + x' - x = 0; \tag 7$

we may divide out $e^{rt}$:

$r^3 - r^2 + r - 1 = 0; \tag 8$

we may factor the cubic on the left:

$r^3 - r^2 + r - 1 = (r^2 + 1)(r - 1); \tag 9$

thus,

$(r^2 + 1)(r - 1) = 0, \tag{10}$

whence

$r = 1, \; r = \pm i; \tag{11}$

we thus find three functions

$f_1(t)= e^t, \; f_2(t) = e^{it}, \; f_3(t) = e^{-it}, \tag{12}$

all of which satisfy (2); taking it as known these $f_i(t)$ are linearly independent, we infer they span the solution space of (2), since it is of order (3); thus the set of solutions to (2) all lie in $V$.